# Retrieving image from real-time database using picasso or glide not working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

I would like to know what is the problem of my code using Picasso or Glide, because when I research the answers for my problem nothing seems to work. Also, I use a button to call out the function.

Here's the sample code that I got on the net and working on it to run:

```
public class View_Img extends AppCompatActivity {
// Initializing the ImageView
ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewimg);

    // getting ImageView by its id
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sendimg);

    // getting the default FirebaseDatabase instance
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    // getting a DatabaseReference for the database root node
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    // Here "image" is the child node value we are getting
    // child node data in the getImage variable
    DatabaseReference getImage = databaseReference.child("image");

    // Adding listener for a single change
    // in the data at this location.
    // this listener will triggered once
    // with the value of the data at the location
    getImage.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // getting a DataSnapshot for the location at the specified
            // relative path and getting in the link variable
            String link = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            // loading that data into img
            // variable which is ImageView
            Glide.with(View_Img.this).load(link).into(img);
        }

        // this will called when any problem
        // occurs in getting data
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //showing that error message in toast
            Toast.makeText(View_Img.this, "Error Loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and I already import necessary things for it to work like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here's the screenshot of the output

[image: output]

Comment: What is value of link variable??

Comment: @Umesh Yadav this would be the value of the link variable "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fireresponseapp-9463f.appspot.com/o/images%2Ffi.jpg?alt=media&token=71a6ee16-1262-4ccc-8527-b174d7c22edb"

Comment: you have provided permission for read file in firbase storage. 

*"Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."*

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: my problem is that an image doesn't show when I run the app using Glide or Picasso. As for the code, I don't have any errors that i find

Comment: as for the permissions and rules, in the firebase storage, I set it to default which allows read and write function while the real-time database I allow only read function

Comment: thank you for all the comments. I manage to resolve my problem by updating my google services.json in which handles the firebase url that is crucial for getting my image link in firebase thank you again.